# yii2 sorting in related model

Tags: php, sorting, yii2, models

have relation

**model Shop.php**

```
  public function getShopAddr()
        {
            return $this->hasOne(SprShopAddr::className(), ['id' => 'shop_addr_id']);
        }
```

**model SprShopAddr.php**

```
public function getDivision()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(SprDivision::className(), ['id' => 'division_id']);
    }
```

**model SprDivision.php**

```
public function getShopAddrs()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(SprShopAddr::className(), ['division_id' => 'id']);
    }
```

**view index.php**

```
 <?= GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            //'filterModel' => $searchModel,
            'summary' =>false, 
            'columns' => [
                'location_code',
                [
                    'label' => 'Дивизион',
                    'attribute' => 'division_id',
                    'value' => 'shopAddr.division.division'
                ],
                ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn', 'template' => '{update}{delete}'],        
            ]
        ]); ?>
```

sort on gridview for field shopAddr.division.division not working. How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

for related model you must configure properly the `setSort` function of the dataProvider

You can find the right information in [this tutorial](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/).

The most important part is that you must define the $dataProvider->setSor(...) function in `yourModelSearch` like this

```
 $dataProvider->setSort([
        'attributes' => [
            'yuorRelatedFieldName' => [
                            'asc' =>    [ $tableRelated . '.yourField' => SORT_ASC ],
                            'desc' =>   [ $tableRelated . '.yourField' => SORT_DESC ],
                            'label' => 'yuorLabel'
            ],                 
        ],
        'defaultOrder' => ['yuorDefaultOrderField' => SORT_ASC],
   ]);
```

Comment: i read this tutorial, my problrm with this relation shopAddr.division.division, 3, not 2 as in tutorial.

Comment: Also in Scenario 3 of the tutorial the sort is managed by `yuorModelSearch`. if you don't configure this part your related field in grid view don't permit the sort