# Sorting in Yii2

Tags: sorting, activerecord, yii2, inner-join

i'm trying to get data from joined tables sorted by specific column. This column is a varchar column but contain only numbers.

The sorting is not working and i have done a lot of research. Please can anyone help me.

what i need is to sort an ActiveDataProvider instance.

this is my code :

```
$dataProviderItems = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => Products::find()->innerJoin('products_trans', 'products_trans.PRODUCT_ID=products.PRODUCT_ID')->innerJoin('items', 'items.PRODUCT_ID=products.PRODUCT_ID')->innerJoin('items_supplieirs', 'items.ITEM_ID=items_supplieirs.ITEM_ID')->innerJoin('suppliers', 'items_supplieirs.SUPPLIER_ID=suppliers.SUPPLIER_ID')->innerJoin('items_trans', 'items_trans.ITEM_ID=items.ITEM_ID')->andFilterWhere(['products_trans.PRODUCT_ID' =>$productID]) ,
            'pagination' => false,
            'sort'=> ['defaultOrder' => ['cast(items_supplieirs.PRICE as unsigned)'=>SORT_ASC]]
    ]);
```

thanks in advance, best regards.

Comment: Ideal way is to create foreign key and create relation of that another model in the main model (getXyx() function), then you may be able to use it directly ... check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32051633/yii2-sorting-in-related-model

Comment: foreign key and relations are created...how i can use them. i have tried to use them but didn't know how to. the problem is that i need to inner join about 6 tables together.

Comment: [Yii2 working with relation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-db-active-record.html#relational-data)